# spring security error handling with JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-security, mybatis

I am trying to handle exception errors from `spring-security` and I am using the following tags in my `web.xml`

```
example:

 <error-page>
     <error-code>403</error-code>
     <location>/test2</location>
 </error-page>
```

If error number 403 occurs then I want to call a controller that will handle these errors and return them in `json` format.

So I am wondering if I can define multiple errors code in my `web.xml`
      example:

```
 <error-page>
     <error-code>403,404,401</error-code>
     <location>/test2</location>
 </error-page> 


without defining a new 
 <error-page> 
    .... 
 </error-page> . ?
```

And second question: How can I send the error information to my controller to give a proper error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your suggestions but i have solved my problem using the following:

in web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <location>/controllerName</location>
</error-page>
```

and then using the following code to get the error number and error message:

```
 Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
 String exceptionMessage = getExceptionMessage(throwable, statusCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to define multiple error-page in order to achieve this.

Additionally you can pass error code to your spring controller and there you can manage errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `@ControllerAdvice` to handle such exceptions.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Error> notFoundHanlder(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        // 404 Your logic here.
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpUnauthorizedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Error> notAuthenticatedHanlder(HttpUnauthorizedException ex) {
        // 401 Your logic here.
    }

    //so on.......

}
```